# How to Extract Values from Dictionaries and Create Lists From Them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
dictionaries = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'test1', 'description': 'foo'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'test2', 'description': 'bar'}
]
```

I would like to separate the values from the keys in each dictionary, making a list of lists like this:

```
[(1 ,'test1', 'foo'), (2, 'test2', 'bar')]
```

I have the following code to perform this...

```
values_list = []

for dict in dictionaries:
    values_list.append(list(dict.values()))
```

When I run this code in my app, I get:

> TypeError: list() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

What's the right way to do this type of list comprehension?

Comment: `[tuple(d.values()) for d in dictionaries]`

Comment: Your (posted) code also has no error. Have you copied the trace from somewhere else?

Comment: Probably somewhere in the full code you replace the python built-in `list()` function with your own definition of `list()` function that takes no argument. That explain why you get the exception

Comment: @caramel1995 thanks for that tip. I'm going to double check the whole app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done with a couple of [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
def get_values_as_tuple(dict_list, keys):
    return [tuple(d[k] for k in keys) for d in dict_list]
```

#### How?

How does this work? This is a nested [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Let's go from the inside out, and start with:

```
tuple(d[k] for k in keys)
```

This creates a tuple of all of the elements in `d` that are specified via `k` in `keys`.  So, that is nice, but what the heck are `d`, `k` and `keys`?

- `keys` is passed to the function, and are the keys we will look for in our dicts.
- `k` is the individual values in `keys` from `k in keys`.
- `d` is the individual dicts in `dict_list` from `d in dict_list`.

The outer comprehension builds a list of the tuples discussed above:

```
[tuple(d[k] for k in keys) for d in dict_list]
```

#### Test Code:

```
dictionaries = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test1', 'description': 'foo'},
                {'id': 2, 'name': 'test2', 'description': 'bar'}]


def get_values_as_tuple(dict_list, keys):
    return [tuple(d[k] for k in keys) for d in dict_list]

print(get_values_as_tuple(dictionaries, ('id', 'name', 'description')))
```

#### Results:

```
[(1, 'test1', 'foo'), (2, 'test2', 'bar')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried this out and it works well. I'm not sure exactly how, though. If I understand correctly, the function you have defined is saying "look in each dictionary from the dictionary-list provided in the first argument. Pull out all the keys as indicated in the second argument and make a tuple from what is left." What does the "[k]" code mean? Is that a shorthand for saying "remove k from d"?

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to convert a list of tuples it so easy with list comprehension technique or the code which you are using it is for list of list but you expected solution looks like list of tuples

```
dictionaries = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test1', 'description': 'foo'}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'test2', 'description': 'bar'}]
values_list = []

for dict in dictionaries:
    values_list.append(tuple(dict.values()))

data = [tuple(dict.values()) for dict in dictionaries]   

print(values_list)
print(data)
```

This might help you which will give you output like this

```
[(1, 'test1', 'foo'), (2, 'test2', 'bar')]
[(1, 'test1', 'foo'), (2, 'test2', 'bar')]
```

Comment: so sorry i used it as a variable from the original question

Answer (score 0):

```
In [14]: dictionaries = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test1', 'description': 
'foo'}, 
   ....: {'id': 2, 'name': 'test2', 'description': 'bar'}]

In [15]: [tuple(d.values()) for d in dictionaries]
Out[15]: [('foo', 1, 'test1'), ('bar', 2, 'test2')]
```

Hi, Trey,`Dict` is disordered in python, so the values in the `tuple` may be disordered too.If you want a ordered result, you may try `OrderedDict` in python.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x:

```
from collections import namedtuple
dictionaries = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'test1', 'description': 'foo'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'test2', 'description': 'bar'}
]
main_list = []
keys = namedtuple("keys",['id','name','description'])
for val in dictionaries:
    data = keys(**val)
    main_list.append((data.id,data.name,data.description))
print(main_list)
>>>[(1, 'test1', 'foo'), (2, 'test2', 'bar')]
```

Python 3.x:

```
dictionaries = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'test1', 'description': 'foo'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'test2', 'description': 'bar'}
]
data = [tuple(val.values()) for val in dictionaries]
print(data)
>>>[(1, 'test1', 'foo'), (2, 'test2', 'bar')]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
dicts = [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'test1', 'description': 'foo'}, 
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'test2', 'description': 'bar'}
        ]

v_list = []

for d in dicts:
    v_list.append( tuple( d.values() ) )

print( v_list )
```

**Results:**

```
[(1, 'test1', 'foo'), (2, 'test2', 'bar')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!